# Shorten the url to domain name in a string in python 2.7

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

suppose i have a string 
`This is a good doll http://www.google.com/a/bs/jdd/etc/etc/a.py`

i would like to get something like this
`This is a good doll www.google.com`

i tried `print re.sub(r'(http://|https://)',"",a))` function in python but i was only able to remove the `http://` part from it .Any ideas on how i could achieve this in python 2.7

Comment: You might want to add your regex attempt

Comment: Use the urlparse lib to parse the url and get the hostname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'This is a good doll http://www.google.com/a/bs/jdd/etc/etc/a.py'
>>> re.sub(r'(?:https?://)([^/]+)(?:\S+)', r"\1", s)
'This is a good doll www.google.com'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use regexes, then you could do something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> the_string = "This is a good doll http://www.google.com/a/bs/jdd/etc/etc/a.py"
>>> def replacement(match):
...     return match.group(2)
... 
>>> re.sub(r"(http://|https://)(.*?)/\S+", replacement, the_string)
'This is a good doll www.google.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> string = "This is a good doll http://www.google.com/a/bs/jdd/etc/etc/a.py"
>>> print string.replace('http://', '').split('/')[0]
This is a good doll www.google.com
```

Comment: This doesn't work if any text follows the URL, e.g. try it with `string = "This is a good doll http://www.google.com/a/bs/jdd/etc/etc/a.py lorem ipsum"`

Comment: It should first match the whole url with a regex and do this only on the url.